# setState warning in ToDo App using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am trying to create a simple ToDo App using React and following is my **app.js** file:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import ToDoList from './toDoList'
import CreateToDos from './createToDos'
import _ from 'lodash'

let toDos = [
    {
        task: 'task 1',
        isCompleted: true
    },
    {
        task: 'task 2',
        isCompleted: false
    }
];

export default class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            toDos
        };

        this.toggleTask()
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Todo App</h1>
                <CreateToDos updateToDoList={ this.updateToDoList.bind(this)}/>
                <ToDoList toDos={this.state.toDos}/>
            </div>
        );
    }

    updateToDoList(task) {
        toDos.push({
            task,
            isCompleted: false
        });
        this.setState({
            toDos
        })
    }

    toggleTask() {
        let updatedToDos = _.map(toDos, function(toDo){
            return _.assign(toDo, {
                task: toDo.task,
                isCompleted: toDo.isCompleted ? false : true
            })
        });
        this.setState({  // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<< Throwing Warning
            toDos: updatedToDos
        })  
    }
}
```

Everything is working perfectly as expected except that I'm getting a warning on my console saying:

> Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted component. This is a no-op. Please check the code for the component.

**I have marked the line that is throwing the warning in the above code.**

Comment: You are calling setState in constructor , which is not allowed.

Comment: where do you expect toggleTask to be called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually the warning comes because you fire setState from your constructor, nl here

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        toDos
    };

    this.toggleTask() // <- this line will call the setState
}
```

As you are inside the constructor, your component wasn't mounted yet. The warning explains it quite good.

You could now choose for using the more appropriate methods for handling state in general

For example, instead of setting `this.state = { toDos }`, you could go for `getInitialState()`. As for updating the state upon mounting, you could use `componentDidMount()`.

Comment: Thanks. It Worked! :)

Answer (score 1):

The error is thrown because you are calling `toggleTask` in the constructor. Instead, try calling it under the `componentDidMount` hook. More information on react components and the lifecycle: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html

Answer (score 0):

component is mounted after the render method return. you are trying to set  local the state of the component during component initialization (at this moment component is not yet completed render method execution).

try this...

```
constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            toDos
        };

        this.toggleTask = this.toggleTask.bind(this);
    }
```

Comment: This will not work, as you are still assigning and unassigned variable to state.